# ANDROID: How to get Available memory before loading files

Tags: android, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I try to load a text file of around 1.2 MB in a word processing apps. I have lot of maxmemory around 20MB. But I get Out of memory error.  Free memory of 0.3 MB How this is possible. Is the maxmemory is occupied by some other processes. If so how to identify the processes and the memory occupied by it.  Is there is way of calculating in prior before loading files.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: which formula you are using for calculating max memory?